# Using BeautifulSoup in Python, it returns None surrounded by '<h4> tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program that asks the user for a baseball player and a card number and it will return the card's value. I am using BeautifulSoup to web scrape https://mavin.io/search?q= and finding the value referenced in the code below. When I type in Mike Ivie, with card number 45T, the program creates the URL, https://mavin.io/search?q=mike+ivie+45T. From there I want to get the price in the green box [Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P28gI.png).
I keep getting this as a result, [Click for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5tWo.png).

Can anyone help out?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

print('\t     Want to know the value of your baseball card?')

print('You found the place, enter the name of the player and the card number below.')

print('Enter "STOP" as the player name when you are done.')

print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

url = 'https://mavin.io/search?q='
choice = False
while not(choice):
    player = input('Player Name: ').lower()
    card_number = input('Card Number: ')
    checkPlayer = list(player)
    for i in range(0,10):
        if str(i) in checkPlayer:
            print()
            print('-----------------------------')
            print('You entered an invalid input!')
            print('-----------------------------')
            continue
    if player == 'stop':
        choice = True
        print()
        print('--------------------------------------------')
        print('Thank you for using this tool. See you again')
        print('--------------------------------------------')
    else:
        #add contents to end of url
        finalPlayer = player.split(' ')
        for i in range(len(finalPlayer)):
            url += finalPlayer[i] + '+'
        url += card_number
        source = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        article = soup.find('div', class_ = 'estimate-box equal-width')
        print(article.h4)
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the URLs you expect the program to visit? What happens when you check the page with a web browser? When you view the source, do you see the matching div and h4 tags? What do they contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is in a json format within the script tags. You can get the whole description (and pull out the value using regex or other means). Or (and you'll have to check), seems they just take the average of the lowPrice and highPrice, so just calculate that out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
import statistics

print('\t     Want to know the value of your baseball card?')

print('You found the place, enter the name of the player and the card number below.')

print('Enter "STOP" as the player name when you are done.')

print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

url = 'https://mavin.io/search?q='
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
choice = False
while not(choice):
    player = input('Player Name: ').lower()
    card_number = input('Card Number: ')
    checkPlayer = list(player)
    for i in range(0,10):
        if str(i) in checkPlayer:
            print()
            print('-----------------------------')
            print('You entered an invalid input!')
            print('-----------------------------')
            continue
    if player == 'stop':
        choice = True
        print()
        print('--------------------------------------------')
        print('Thank you for using this tool. See you again')
        print('--------------------------------------------')
    else:
        #add contents to end of url
        finalPlayer = player.split(' ')
        for i in range(len(finalPlayer)):
            url += finalPlayer[i] + '+'
        url += card_number
        source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        script = soup.find_all('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})[1]
        jsonData = json.loads(script.string)[0]
        description = jsonData['description']
        highPrice = float(jsonData['offers']['highPrice'])
        lowPrice = float(jsonData['offers']['lowPrice'])
        average = round(statistics.mean([highPrice, lowPrice]),2)
        print(description)
```

**Output:**

```
Value estimate of $4.35. Based on 2 similar items sold in the Baseball Cards category.
```

Here's the calculated average:

```
print(average)
4.35
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the price lives in h3.sold-price. That's all I know. Hope it helps. This is not an answer, just an observation.

Comment: Make it an answer then e.g. if the correct syntax is `soup.select_one('h3.sold-price').text` add that to your answer. I'm guessing you put this here due to not having enough rep to post a comment, unsure on that one, but this area is for answers. If it is just a comment it should go as a comment.